# JAX-RS: Dependency Injection with Shutdown/Destroy/Dispose

Tags: dependency-injection, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

#### Actual Problem

I’m trying to create a simple JAX-RS `Application` with Jersey 2.0 like this:

```java
@ApplicationPath("")
public class MyService extends ResourceConfig {

  public MyService() {

    packages(MyService.class.getPackage().getName());
    register(new ApplicationBinder());
  }


  private static class ApplicationBinder extends AbstractBinder {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {

      MyDependency dep = new MyDependency();
      bind(dep).to(MyDependency.class);
      // TODO properly shutdown/destroy/dispose "dep" somewhere
    }

  }

}
```

`MyDependency` objects are a little expensive to create and they have a `shutdown()` method which needs to be called before destruction. Where and how should I do such cleanup tasks with JAX-RS?

#### More Background (if Necessary)

The JAX-RS resource implementation which uses the created `MyDependency` object looks like this – if that should be of any relevance to the problem:

```java
@Path("getit")
@Singleton
public class MyResource {

  private final MyDependency dependency;

  @Inject
  public MyResource(MyDependency dependency) {

    this.dependency = dependency;
  }

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
  public String getIt() {

    return this.dependency.getIt();
  }

}
```

Comment: When `MyDependency` needs to be disposed of? Also, are you using a JavaEE 7 Application Server (i.e Glassfish )?

Comment: @CarloPellegrini  `MyDependency` needs to be properly shutdown when the servlet is [destroyed](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Servlet.html#destroy%28%29). I’m targetting any Servlet 3.0 compatible containers, ideally without having to write a `web.xml` file (hence the `@ApplicationPath` annotation).

Answer (score 1):

*Servlet 3.0 compatible containers* means that you can't rely on CDI being available, so we are struck with hk2.

Implementing `org.glassfish.hk2.api.PreDestroy` on `MyDependency` should instruct the binding framework to do the proper cleanup.

At shutdown hk2 should call the `preDestroy()` method defined by the interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried to implement [`PreDestroy`](https://hk2.java.net/nonav/hk2-api/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/PreDestroy.html) with both `MyDependency` and `ApplicationBinder`. However, none of the two `preDestroy()` methods is ever called. I have tested this with Jetty 9.0.4.v20130625 which should have been supporting [Servlet 3.0 since version 8.x](http://eclipse.org/jetty/about.php). Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: PreDestroy and PostConstruct only work if your class is container-managed, that's probably the issue (or at least it was for me)